# antlr: Best practice to integrate generated parser into the system

Tags: java, antlr

Here is the background, I am trying to create a DSL to allow customer write simple scripts to query into our mongodb based database. I choose antlr to implement the DSL.

From my understanding (and pls let me know if it's not correct) there are 2 approaches to integrate antlr generated parser into the system:

1. Embed code into the grammar file so that the generated parser could
   be used directly to make query to the database and return result in
   a certain format (e.g. json encoded)
2. Keep the parser purely a parser, after feed the DSL file to it, and construct the query in another class by retrieving the AST from generated parser class

So antlrers, which one do you think is the way I as an antlr newbie should go? Can you list the pros and cos of each approach, or you have other way to recommend?

Comment: There is no single "best way". Personally, I like to keep my grammar as empty as possible (as little embedded code as is possible). I created a few blog posts on how to parse and evaluate a small programming language (using ANTLR) here: http://bkiers.blogspot.nl/2011/03/creating-your-own-programming-language.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not embed business logic into your parser, because of potential maintenance headaches: you do not want to recompile your grammar to fix bugs in business logic, let alone the nightmarish prospects of having to debug your business logic inside a generated parser. So option one should be out of the question for anything other than the smallest toy projects.

Option two can be implemented in more than one way: you can (A) have ANTLR generate AST nodes for you, and write a tree parser, or (B) you could skip the tree parser, and produce your own representation in the actions of the parser. I tried both approaches on production projects, both in Java and in C#, and both these approaches worked very well. I think the choice between (A) and (B) is largely a matter of your personal taste, as long as the business logic is kept out of the parser.

Comment: Hi thx a lot, your points make sense to me. So can you send me an example of how you produce your own representation of the parser?

Comment: @green For obvious reasons, I cannot send you code that belongs to my company. There's nothing special to it, though: I use `returns [DslNodeType res]` in each rule, where `DslNodeType` is the class that represents the thing I parse: a binary expression, a variable, etc. P.S. It's probably not a good idea to post your e-mail address unprotected in a web page visible to everybody :)

Comment: thx. You are right, i've removed my mail address. BTW, I've figured my way and it's pretty simple: 1. Create a super class which contains several data structures and protected methods to mutate them; 2. In the .g file, set superClass option to point to that super class; 3. In the rules add an action to update the super class fields, e.g. `period_type: ('day' | 'month' | 'wee') {setPeriod($period_type.text);}`

Comment: @green Congratulations on independently discovering the [Generation Gap](http://www.research.ibm.com/designpatterns/pubs/gg.html) design pattern :)

Comment: thx @dasblinkenlight! At the moment I'm headache on how to implement the domain arithmetic evaluation. Say I can fetch some aggregation data from database based on the DSL spec now, but there are derived columns like `colA / (colB + colA) AS colC`, looks like it needs a smart composite design pattern here... Do you got any idea?

Comment: @green There are dozens of expression evaluators out there (here's a link to the one from [apache](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/jspapi/javax/servlet/jsp/el/ExpressionEvaluator.html)). You can take one of them and adjust to suit your needs, or use an open source engine as an inspiration for your own evaluator.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13087/discussion-between-green-and-dasblinkenlight)